# Sum only cells that contain notes/comments in Excel

Tags: excel, sum, worksheet

I have several sheets included in an Excel file and I need to sum some cells, but ONLY the ones that contain notes/comments, those that are inserted with Shift + F2.

Each cell has a value, and they all have notes/comments, and each comment refers to a different product.

Excel itself has a function to find all the comments, whether from the worksheet or the entire archive. It helps, it returns me all the cells that contain the comment that I searched AND the values of the cell, however it does not add up all the values, and I need that.

How can I do it? Thanks!

I used Excel's native function to find values, which worked. However, it returns me a cell-by-cell report, and does not add up all the values.

Comment: If VBA is allowed (which I think is needed, this could be helpful: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1872-excel-filter-cells-with-comments.html )

Comment: The sum of the selected cells will be displayed in the status bar, if that helps (if not displayed, can change by right-clicking the status bar)

Comment: (I'm assuming that you know this trick to select all comment cells - aka notes in Excel 365) https://www.teachexcel.com/excel-tutorial/quickly-find-all-comments-in-a-spreadsheet-in-excel_1223.html